# Object is not iterable Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've model called Order. The problem appears when I attempt to initial with a queryset. I get 'Order' object is not iterable, i think cause of get_queryset called twice

views.py

```
class ChechoutViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):

  serializer_class = serializers.OrderSerializer

  queryset = None  # this line is probably not required, but some code checking tools like it to be defined.

  def get_queryset(self):

      cart_obj, cart_created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user_profile=self.request.user)
      billing_obj, billing_created = BillingProfile.objects.get_or_create(user_profile=self.request.user)

      if billing_obj is not None:
          self.queryset = models.Order.objects.new_or_get(billing_obj=billing_obj, cart_obj=cart_obj)

      return self.queryset
```

models.py

```
class OrderManager(models.Manager):

  def new_or_get(self, billing_obj, cart_obj):
    qs = Order.objects.filter(billing_profile=billing_obj, cart=cart_obj, active=True)

      if qs.exists():
        obj = qs
      else:
        obj = Order.objects.create(billing_profile=billing_obj, cart=cart_obj)

      return obj
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CheckoutViewSet.get_queryset` method is not always returning a `QuerySet` because of the `OrderManager.new_or_get` method.

In `OrderManager.new_or_get` if the queryset does not exist (`if qs.exists()`), you are returning a single object from the call to `Order.objects.create` and this is also returned by `CheckoutViewSet.get_queryset`.

You could amend the `CheckoutViewSet.get_queryset` method to check the return type from `new_or_get` and use that to return a queryset, I've included an example below:

views.py

```
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet

class ChechoutViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):

  serializer_class = serializers.OrderSerializer

  queryset = Order.objects.all()  # You should include this because it can be used to statically inspect the view

  def get_queryset(self):

      cart_obj, cart_created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user_profile=self.request.user)
      billing_obj, billing_created = BillingProfile.objects.get_or_create(user_profile=self.request.user)

      ### Changes below
      if billing_obj is not None:
          order = models.Order.objects.new_or_get(billing_obj=billing_obj, cart_obj=cart_obj)
          if not isinstance(order, QuerySet):
             queryset = Order.objects.filter(pk=order.pk)
          else:
             queryset = order
          self.queryset = queryset

      return self.queryset
```

If you `OrderManage.new_or_get` method does not return a QuerySet then this presumes it is an instance of `Order` and returns a QuerySet by filtering for that object by its primary key.  This will result in a QuerySet with a single instance.

Answer (score 1):

The line `obj = Order.objects.create(billing_profile=billing_obj, cart=cart_obj)` creates the item in db and then returns it in the `return obj` line. However `get_queryset` should return a queryset. I would suggested doing the following:

```
if qs.exists():
    obj = qs
else:
    obj_created = Order.objects.create(billing_profile=billing_obj, cart=cart_obj)
    obj = Order.objects.filter(id=obj_created.id)
```

I would suggest making sure the type of the return value is as intended.